# Pre-order instead of add to card

Tags: magento2

I want to Display Pre order instead of add to card in the Listing page based on some conditions (Qty, and Stock status) in magento 2.4.5

Comment: Can you confirm that you want only the label of the button to be changed, but the rest of the process (adding the product, checkout process, ...) will remain the same ?

Comment: Also, there are **a lot** of templates with the "Add to cart" button. Do you want to apply this logic to all of them ? Only in the product listed in the category ? On the related/upsell/cross-sell products ?

Comment: yes only the label , yes all of them

Answer (score 0):

To Set the Pre Order Follow the Following steps

1. Create a custom translation file:

In your Magento 2 theme directory, navigate to **app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme}/i18n**.
Create a new directory named en_US (assuming you're using the English language).
Inside the en_US directory, create a file named csv (e.g., en_US.csv).

2. Open the **en_US.csv** file and add the following entry:

   "Add to Cart","Pre Order"
3. Save the changes to the **en_US.csv** file.
4. Clear the cache:

Flush the Magento cache to ensure the translation changes take effect.

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
```